# Dynamically Update Elements of Array (Based on Changes Made to its Other Elements)

Tags: c++, search, vector, dynamic-programming, algebra

So, I have a 2D vector of cracks on a surface, arranged in no particular order.  If a crack is too close another crack (let's say 3 units), one or both of the cracks must be translated away (maximum amount 8 units).  Type B cracks (which have been identified) will not be modified.  My program so far has the functionality to translate the cracks along or perpendicular to their lines of equation.

The problem arises when I translate a crack away from another, and it gets too close to a different, third crack.  This requires a second translation, and if the issue isn't fixed, a third one as well.  But this gets computationally intensive.  If 278 cracks are moved on the first iteration, and then another 278 on the second, and again on the third, that's already 277^3 = 21,253,933 calculations (for each crack, the distance to 277 other cracks must be calculated) before the translation.  Now it's not always that all 278 cracks will have to be translated, but I need a better algorithm to move all cracks so that they are at least 3 units of distance away from each other.  Even if I try to use a dynamic search neighborhood, it will still have to loop over all 278 cracks.

Please advise; I'm stuck and I really don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use as surface blocks the following struct

```
struct Square{
bool occupied;
Square *crack;
};
```

Then you could mark occupied any squares with cracks in them by:

```
surf[x][y].occupied = true;
```

Also, you could create a "territory" around your crack, which would be full of blocks with

```
surf[x][y]->crack
```

i.e. pointers to the crack that causes it to be unavailable (or NULL if free)

Therefore when you start the game you can simply start constructing the territory for each crack, until a conflict happens(a territory is already occupied) in which case, you can move the crack away(don't forget to move its territory).
Therefore, you would simply have to check if a crack is in the territory of another one, and if it is you should move it (just search for empty squares around). When moved successfully to an empty square (or exceed move limit), you can now create its own territory. If while building the territory you come across a square with territory already, simply use the pointer to move it (and its territory). This would help you not need to compare each crack with all others, and make the process much more efficient. Also, if you don't want to move a crack more than once you could keep track of whether it has been moved with another boolean, and you can determine the best direction. Just throwing some thoughts out there. Hope this helps!

Comment: instead of the pointer, you could alternatively use two ints for the coordinates of the crack, or -1 if empty

Comment: I think it's a good idea to implement this as the cracks are being read from the XML.  By looking behind for each crack that is read in, all cracks will be accounted for by the time the last crack is reached.  Thank you for helping me realize this.